# Cómo mostrar datos de JSON (url google sheet) en Wordpress?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Quisiera mostrar a cada usuario logueado en wordpress datos únicos para cada uno desde una hoja de cálculo (googlesheet), lo traigo por url, los datos son del tipo JSON.

URL (omito api_key): https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1NJVlXXVA8mCiaomAAcSIZ9RHY2C7CHtyioVoBabtPTY/values/libreta-global!A1:B1?&key=xxxxx

JSON:

```
{
  "range": "'libreta-global'!A1:B1",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "Alumno",
      "Nota"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, mira para mostrar los datos JSON de una hoja de cálculo de Google Sheets en WordPress, tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

- Instala y activa el plugin "Insert PHP Code Snippet" en tu sitio de WordPress.
- Crea un nuevo Snippet (apariencia -> Insertar snippet PHP) y incluye el siguiente código php:

```
<?php
// URL de la hoja de cálculo de Google Sheets
$url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1NJVlXXVA8mCiaomAAcSIZ9RHY2C7CHtyioVoBabtPTY/values/libreta-global!A1:B1?key=YOUR_API_KEY';

// Obtener datos JSON desde la URL
$response = wp_remote_get($url);

// Verificar si la solicitud fue exitosa
if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    echo 'Error al obtener los datos.';
} else {
    // Decodificar el JSON y obtener los valores
    $data = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);
    
    // Comprobar si se obtuvieron datos válidos
    if (isset($data['values']) && is_array($data['values']) && count($data['values']) > 0) {
        $alumno = $data['values'][0][0];
        $nota = $data['values'][0][1];
        
        // Mostrar los datos en el front-end
        echo 'Alumno: ' . $alumno . '<br>';
        echo 'Nota: ' . $nota;
    } else {
        echo 'No se encontraron datos válidos en la hoja de cálculo.';
    }
}
```

La parte de mostrar los datos en tu Front-End depende de ti entonces, pero por lo menos ya tienes los datos en tu php.

Si los datos son fijos en la hoja de excel puedes trabajar en base a una importación a tu base de datos y evitar estar consumiendo la api de google sheet a cada rato... implementa algo como firebase...